# trouble importing large excel file cell range into Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, xlsread

I've been trying to import an excel file into Matlab R2014a for my research project. I have to select a certain range to look at. I want to look at the range from column K all the way to column AD, my question is, what is the max amount of cell data matlab can import from excel? When I run the line of code, it gives me many numbers, but none of those numbers are on my excel file. I'm thinking the issue may be that my range is too large, because when I use a smaller range, like from column N to column P, it gives me the correct numbers. Please let me know if there is a better, more effective way to  import this data.To select the range, I've used the coding below.

```
[Run.xls,All_Angles] = uigetfile('Run.xls','All_Angles');
fileName = Run.xls;
sheet = 'All_Angles';
xlRange = 'K1:AD5001;
subsetA = xlsread(filename, sheet, xlRange);
```

When I run the last line, I get an output, it just isn't any of the numbers I see on that sheet of my excel file.

When checking the dimensions of the output, it returns 5000   20, which appears to be the size of my range, it's just the returned numbers don't appear in my excel file.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try to include a bit more of your import code. The problem could be there but we need to see it.

Comment: @Hoki I've added more of my code, hopefully this helps

Comment: What is the size of the output you get in `subsetA`?

Comment: The size of the output 5000 by 20, which I added to the post above.  The output doesn't match the numbers in my excel file though @nkjt

Comment: If it's returning the right size, but with the wrong numbers, it doesn't seem like the actual size is an issue. Have you got the right file/sheet name being passed in? (You're doing something weird with `uigetfile` there). The other option is that somewhere within that block there's a value you don't expect and it's screwing with your output. How different are the numbers you get-- just random values?

Comment: The sheet name and file are correct, I checked the outputted numbers with other sheets in the file and they're not showing up anywhere. What's weird with my uigetfile? what is it supposed to look like. And my outputted numbers seem systematic, but random. Like in column one, it starts at like 4.1andsomenumbers and counts all the way to 5.000. I'm not sure what is going on. @nkjt